# How to prevent NaN/NULL values from Pandas df getting quoted after using csv.QUOT_ALL option?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have pandas df which I need to load in postgres db. Since some values contains special chars & delimiters, I need to use quoting = csv.QUOTE_ALL option as follows: -

```
df.to_csv(r"test.csv",index=False,sep='|',quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
```

csv.QUOATE_ALL ensures special chars getting handled properly. However it's quoting even NaN values from df in csv file. So when I load from csv to db using COPY command, it throughs error for non char dtype columns as --

```
invalid input syntax for timestamp - ""
```

This is because output column data type is timestamp but value contains "", as we quoted all values.
So how to prevent NaN values from df getting quoted ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would advise against using CSV for anything that might contain NULL values, as CSV does not have any concept of NULL. (Hm, come to think of it, I'd probably advise against using CSV for anything at all...). Having said that, what goes wrong with QUOTE_MINIMAL?

Comment: @TurePalsson - there is one CRLF charachter in one of the record & pd.to_csv function while writing to csv is not quoting it when I use csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL 7 hence it's failing. 
So issue is csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL is not quoting it & csv.QUOTE_ALL is quoting everything.